# Cannot use cargo patch with a git dependency in Docker

Tags: git, docker, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build a docker container with some bleeding-edge crates that are available in git but not in crates.io. Moreover, those git dependencies depend on each other in a bit of a difficult way, so I have to use the `patch` section of the `Cargo.toml` file. Also, the project is in a workspace with multiple sub-crates.

The project compiles perfectly in local doing `cargo build --bin frontend`, but it fails to compile inside docker, giving the following error:

```
STEP 13: RUN cargo vendor > .cargo/config
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel`
error: failed to sync

Caused by:
  failed to load pkg lockfile

Caused by:
  failed to resolve patches for `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `diesel`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel?rev=0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94#0744b7e6

Caused by:
  object not found - no match for id (0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94); class=Odb (9); code=NotFound (-3)
Error: error building at STEP "RUN cargo vendor > .cargo/config": error while running runtime: exit status 101
```

As far as I can tell, it seems that it cannot find the revision with that commit hash in that GitHub repo, but I can see it [here](https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel/commit/0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94), and it works perfectly outside of docker.

This is the patching configuration:

```
[patch.crates-io.diesel]
git = "https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel"
rev = "0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94"

[patch.crates-io.diesel_derives]
git = "https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel"
rev = "0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94"

[patch.crates-io.diesel_migrations]
git = "https://github.com/GiGainfosystems/diesel"
rev = "0744b7e6e05582bf8fca21c0a5fbba08555abd94"
```

**Do you know if I need to provide any git configuration to cargo to access this repository? or what do you think it could be happening?**

For reference, this is the dockerfile configuration:

```
FROM rustlang/rust:nightly-alpine3.12 AS rust_builder
WORKDIR /root/rustbuild/
RUN apk -U upgrade
RUN apk add libpq

COPY Cargo.lock .
COPY Cargo.toml .
RUN mkdir .cargo

COPY backend ./backend
COPY frontend ./frontend
COPY common ./common
COPY scheduler ./scheduler
COPY cli_utils ./cli_utils

RUN cargo vendor > .cargo/config

RUN cargo build --bin frontend
```

Note that I'm using `rustlang/rust:nightly-alpine3.12` as the Rust container because I need a nightly compiler, and Alpine for multiple reasons, among them the fact that this also includes a NodeJS part that would also use the same Alpine version.

Comment: Try to remove Cargo.lock from dockerfile, will it work?

Comment: It seems that the issue persists :( and, Ideally, I would like to keep the lock file in order to have exactly the same dependency tree.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm stuck at the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the branch where this commit was had already been force-pushed on top of it, and therefore, the commit was "shadowed". Cargo doesn't let you use a commit if it's not part of any branch in the repository.

The solution was to use a commit that was part of a branch.